# No Way to get the console handle (Dev-Pascal)

Tags: console, pascal, handle

I've tried the simple program for my exercise but if i compiled, it turned give a message *"No Way to get the console handle"* (Dev-Pascal).

Here's my code:

```
program square;
uses crt;

var
side,circumference,broad:real;

begin
    write('Input the side value of the square: ');
    readln(side);

    circumference := 4 * side;
    broad := side * side;

    writeln('The circumference value of the square = ', circumference);
    writeln('The abroad value of the square = ', broad);
    writeln();

    write('Press any key...');
    readkey();
end.
```

thank you for helping and teaching me
i would appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Dev-pascal comes with a 10+ years old Free Pascal version. I really have no idea. Try to run the example on the cmdline to see if dev-pascal is the cause or something else. Temporarily disable security software might also be something to try.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you've created a **`Window Skeleton`** project.
It has it's description: *A Windows skeleton application (no window)*.

In this case you'll get this error though you code compiles (I've got this error too with your code).

Try to create **`Console Application`** project which has it's own description: *A standard console-based (MS-DOS) application* (Your code has compiled and the program worked as well).

P.S. Can't say what exactly happens -- couldn't find any documentation about errors in Dev-Pas (1.9.2).
My assumption is that *skeleton* program doesn't imply console window for execution program while *console application* does.

Answer (score 0):

just close the project and then re-open the pascal source file (.pas). And maybe put "readln;" just before "END.".